# To give STDIN for Sed?

Tags: terminal, bash, text

Pseudocommand

```
echo '1,2,3,5' | sed -n data.txt
```

which gives

```
sed: 1: "data.txt": extra characters at the end of d command
```

I want to give linenumbers for search from other command. 
Actually awk is giving those numbers from this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209781/16920).

data.txt:

```
hello 
amigo
this line 3
and here we go 4
and 5 is here
```

where output should be

```
hello 
amigo
this line 3
and 5 is here
```

How can you give sed those linenumbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can do something like

```
eval $(echo sed $(for i in 1 2 3 5; do echo "-e ${i}p"; done) -n data.txt )
```

---

To read the line numbers from a file containing the numbers, separated by space, use

```
eval $(echo sed $(for i in $(< line-numbers.txt); do echo "-e ${i}p"; done) -n data.txt )
```

In this case, you can use *any* command which produces a list of line number instead of the `< line-numbers.txt` part.

---

Or, if the numbers in the file are separated by `,`

```
eval $(echo sed $(for i in $(tr \, ' ' < line-numbers.txt); do echo "-e ${i}p"; done) -n data.txt )
```

(and again, the command can be anything producing line numbers separated by `,`)

Comment: Any better idea how to do this better? I am really open to any innovation. To get linenumbers from a command and give them to Sed.

Comment: How do say `i in [numbers-in-file]`? I tried `i in data.txt` unsuccessfully, also unsuccessfully `i in \`cat data.txt\``. data.txt here `1,2,3`.

Comment: `data.txt` contains the text, doesn't it? You can do `for i in $(cat line-numbers.txt); do` but this requires the numbers to be separated by space, not by comma.

Comment: or use `$(cat line-numbers.txt | tr , ' ')` to replace comma by space.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using `sed` with `xargs`.

```
echo '1p;2p;3p;5p' filename | xargs sed -n
```

Basically `sed` uses the format `<line-number>p` to display a line. You can separate several lines using `;`.

Comment: and assuming you can't change the input you can do `echo 1,2,3,5|sed -e 's/,/p;/' -e 's/$/p filename/'|xargs sed -n`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the output from your `awk` command is `1,2,3,5`, you can do this:

```
sed -n $(my_awk_commamd | sed 's/,/p;/g;s/$/p;/') data.txt
```

The `sed` inside the `$(` command substitution converts `1,2,3,5` to the sed expression `1p;2p;3p;5p;`, which is then interpreted by the outer `sed` over the data file.

A unit test, replacing awk with a simple `echo`:

```
$ sed -n $(echo '1,2,3,5' | sed 's/,/p;/g;s/$/p;/') data.txt 
hello 
amigo
this line 3
and 5 is here
$
```